# Jenkins + kubernetes plugin + connection issues with k8s api

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, connection

We have installed jenkins inside a kubernetes cluster via a helm chart: https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts

> Kubernetes server version: 1.21.6

> Installed helm chart version: jenkins helm chart: 3.8.9

> jenkins version image: "jenkins/jenkins:2.303.3-alpine"

There are some issues with the underlying k8s api connection. Sometimes it works and sometimes we get k8s api error response:

[image]

> Error testing connection https://kubernetes.default:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/jenkins_home/.kube/config (No such
> file or directory)

The jenkins helm chart does the autowring of jenkins serviceaccount + roles + rolebindings + jenkins secret token. So there is no need of a `/var/jenkins_home/.kube/config` file.

I'm a bit at a loss what the precise issue is.

Here are some logs:

The k8s api error:

```
Autoconfiguring Kubernetes client
Nov 25, 2021 1:02:43 PM FINE org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesFactoryAdapter
Creating Kubernetes client: KubernetesFactoryAdapter [serviceAddress=, namespace=kring-jenkins, caCertData=null, credentials=null, skipTlsVerify=false, connectTimeout=0, readTimeout=0]
Nov 25, 2021 1:02:43 PM FINE org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesFactoryAdapter
Proxy Settings for Cloud: false
Nov 25, 2021 1:02:43 PM FINE org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud
Error testing connection 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/jenkins_home/.kube/config (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory.createParser(YAMLFactory.java:354)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory.createParser(YAMLFactory.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3495)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.KubeConfigUtils.parseConfig(KubeConfigUtils.java:42)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.TokenRefreshInterceptor.intercept(TokenRefreshInterceptor.java:44)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.lambda$createApplicableInterceptors$6(HttpClientUtils.java:284)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:257)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:541)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:504)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:487)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.listRequestHelper(BaseOperation.java:163)
Caused: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [list]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [null]  in namespace: [kring-jenkins]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.listRequestHelper(BaseOperation.java:170)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:672)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:86)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud$DescriptorImpl.doTestConnection(KubernetesCloud.java:730)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:393)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:405)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:77)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:208)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:141)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:536)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:281)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:694)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:156)
    at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:80)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:153)
    at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:128)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:153)
    at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:153)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:92)
    at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:53)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:92)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:97)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:62)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:109)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Deployed helm chart

```
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
agent:
  alwaysPullImage: false
  componentName: jenkins-agent
  containerCap: 5
  customJenkinsLabels: []
  defaultsProviderTemplate: ""
  enabled: true
  envVars:
  - name: JENKINS_URL
    value: http://jenkins.kring-jenkins.svc.cluster.local:8080/
  - name: DIND
    value: "false"
  image: jenkins/inbound-agent
  imagePullSecretName: null
  jenkinsTunnel: jenkins-agent.kring-jenkins.svc.cluster.local:50000
  jenkinsUrl: http://jenkins.kring-jenkins.svc.cluster.local:8080
  kubernetesConnectTimeout: 90
  kubernetesReadTimeout: 90
  maxRequestsPerHostStr: "5"
  namespace: kring-jenkins
  nodeSelector: {}
  nodeUsageMode: NORMAL
  podRetention: Never
  privileged: true
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 512m
      memory: 1024Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 256m
      memory: 256Mi
  runAsGroup: null
  runAsUser: 1000
  showRawYaml: true
  tag: 4.11-1
  volumes:
  - hostPath: /var/run/docker.sock
    mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
    type: HostPath
  websocket: false
  workingDir: /home/jenkins/agent
checkDeprecation: true
clusterZone: cluster.local
controller:
  JCasC:
    configScripts:
      global-security: |
        jenkins:
          securityRealm:
            local:
              allowsSignup: false
              enableCaptcha: false
              users:
                - id: ${ADMIN_USER}
                  password: ${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
                - id: jenkins-job-builder
                  password: jenkins-job-builder
                - id: operator
                  password: operator
          authorizationStrategy:
            loggedInUsersCanDoAnything:
              allowAnonymousRead: false
      jobs: |
        jobs:
          - script: >
              folder('devops');
              pipelineJob('devops/jenkins-job-creator') {
                definition {
                  triggers {
                    scm('* * * * *')
                  }
                  cpsScm {
                    scm {
                      git {
                        remote {
                          url('git@bitbucket.org:kg_kring/jenkins-jobs.git')
                          credentials('k8s-secret-ssh-git')
                        }
                        branches('master')
                        scriptPath('Jenkinsfile')
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
      unclassified: |
        unclassified:
          globalLibraries:
            libraries:
              - name: "jenkins-utils"
                defaultVersion: "master"
                includeInChangeSets: false
                retriever:
                  modernSCM:
                    scm:
                      git:
                        id: "jenkins-utils"
                        remote: "git@bitbucket.org:kg_kring/jenkins-utils.git"
                        credentialsId: "k8s-secret-ssh-git"
          bitbucketBuildStatusNotifier:
            globalCredentialsId: "k8s-secret-bitbucket-status-notifier"
          slackNotifier:
            teamDomain: groeipakketteam # i.e. <worskpace-name>.slack.com
            tokenCredentialId: k8s-secret-slack-token
      welcome-message: |
        jenkins:
          systemMessage: Welkom op de Jenkins server van het KRING team!
    enabled: true
  adminSecret: true
  adminUser: admin
  agentListenerEnabled: true
  agentListenerHostPort: null
  agentListenerPort: 50000
  agentListenerServiceType: ClusterIP
  authorizationStrategy: |-
    <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
      <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
    </authorizationStrategy>
  componentName: jenkins-master
  csrf:
    defaultCrumbIssuer:
      enabled: true
      proxyCompatability: true
  enableXmlConfig: true
  image: jenkins/jenkins
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  ingress:
    annotations:
      ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-request-headers: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https||X-Forwarded-Port
        443'
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    enabled: true
    hostName: kring-jenkins.groeipakketapplicatie.be
    tls: null
  installPlugins:
  - configuration-as-code:1.54
  - workflow-durable-task-step:2.40
  - command-launcher:1.6
  - credentials-binding:1.27
  - git:4.10.0
  - jdk-tool:1.5
  - job-dsl:1.77
  - kubernetes:1.30.11
  - mailer:1.34
  - matrix-auth:2.6.8
  - ssh-agent:1.23
  - warnings-ng:9.8.0
  - workflow-aggregator:2.6
  - workflow-job:2.42
  - bitbucket-build-status-notifier:1.4.2
  - kubernetes-credentials-provider:0.20
  - authorize-project:1.4.0
  - slack:2.48
  - parameterized-scheduler:1.0
  - uno-choice:2.5.7
  - scriptler:3.4
  javaOpts: -Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=Europe/Brussels -Dorg.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.PodTemplate.connectionTimeout=60
    -Dorg.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator.websocketConnectionTimeout=60
  jenkinsUrl: https://kring-jenkins.groeipakketapplicatie.be
  jenkinsUrlProtocol: https
  nodePort: 8080
  overwritePlugins: true
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 4000m
      memory: 8192Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 200m
      memory: 256Mi
  scriptApproval:
  - method com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHUserPrivateKey getPrivateKey
  - method com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.IdCredentials getId
  - method java.lang.Process waitFor
  - staticMethod com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider lookupCredentials
    java.lang.Class hudson.model.ItemGroup
  - staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance
  - staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods execute java.util.List
  - staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods size java.lang.CharSequence
  - staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProcessGroovyMethods consumeProcessOutput
    java.lang.Process java.lang.Appendable java.lang.Appendable
  securityRealm: <securityRealm class="hudson.security.LegacySecurityRealm"/>
  servicePort: 8080
  serviceType: ClusterIP
  sideCars:
    configAutoReload:
      enabled: true
      folder: /var/jenkins_home/casc_configs
      image: kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar:1.14.2
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 100Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 100Mi
      sshTcpPort: 1044
  tag: 2.303.3-alpine
  targetPort: 8080
persistence:
  accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  enabled: true
  existingClaim: jenkins
  size: 100Gi
  storageClass: managed-nfs-storage-default
rbac:
  create: true
  readSecrets: true
serviceAccount:
  create: true
```

Comment: You can try to create an issue in their [github project](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/issues) so developers can look into and suggest what exactly happens

Comment: Ok, so was an infra issue, the machine (VM running the cluster) went down a couple days before causing an issue with time synchronization. Some of the nodes (inside the cluster) were running on the machine with the incorrect current time. So that's why we sometimes got a 401 auth errors because the JWT token is time based

Comment: Thank you for answering. You may post [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it. It can be useful for community if someone accidentally runs into the same issue.